Excel VBA to Insert Newer Style of Checkbox
There is a much nicer looking / easier to work with version of checkbox available in Excel, through the "Insert -> Controls -> Checkbox" ribbon path (NOT the developer options path).
Is there a VBA method to insert such a checkbox?
Not looking for these:
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add
ActiveSheet.Controls.Add

Thank you.

Yes, there is, and the Macro Recorder reveals the appropriate syntax(!)

Avoid unnecessary selection! Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cellcontrol

taller's comment solves this:
Range("A1:A5").CellControl.SetCheckbox

